# Dynamic Progressbar in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, model-view-controller

So here is what I want to do:

I have a Project in MVC that sends messages to users who belong to a group.
the actual sending process is handled in the Controller. But to not let the User who sends the message wait an undefined time until the process is finished, I want to display a progressbar in the View. My first Idea was to meassure the time it takes to send one message, and let the bar progress related to that calculation. But as that may varry, I thought it would be better, to let it progress one step everytime one message got send.

The Problem is, that the sending process in the Controller is inside a loop, and I don't know if it is possible to send some info to the View after each loop without breaking the process of sending messages.

Is there a way to do this, or should I rather then a progressbar show a circleanimation until the process finishes instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr).

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes
>   developing real-time web functionality easy. SignalR allows
>   bi-directional communication between server and client. Servers can
>   now push content to connected clients instantly as it becomes
>   available. SignalR supports Web Sockets, and falls back to other
>   compatible techniques for older browsers. SignalR includes APIs for
>   connection management (for instance, connect and disconnect events),
>   grouping connections, and authorization.

Here's an example: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1124691/SignalR-Progress-Bar-Simple-Example-Sending-Live-D

Comment: WOW, Thanks for the fast answer, I didn't think someone would respond so fast. I will take a look at it, thanks so much!